# Aligning Independent Sub equation environments horizontally

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, subequations

I want to horizontally align the equality signs of all three or last two sub equation environments defined separately.

Code:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\alpha_1 &=\frac{1}{4}\left[(L-1)^2 + \tan ^2\left(\frac{2\pi}{M}\right)(L+1)^2\right]\\
\alpha_2 &= 1 \\
\alpha_3 &=\alpha_1\\
\alpha_4 &=\alpha_1
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
The angle $\theta$ values are
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\theta_1 &= \tan^{-1} \left[\frac{L+1}{L-1}\tan\left(\frac{2\pi}{M}\right)\right]\\
\theta_2 &= \pi - \theta_1\\
\theta_3 &=\theta_1\\
\theta_4 &=\frac{(M-2)\pi}{M} - \theta_1\\[5pt]
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
and
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\phi_1 &= \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta_1\\
\phi_2 &= \frac{2\pi}{M}\\
\phi_3 &= \phi_1\\
\phi_4 &= \frac{2\pi}{M} + \theta_1 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Just a comment: I'd rather speak of a *vertical* alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple hack, using the `eqparbox` package: I put the r.h.s. of each first subequation in an `\eqmathbox` (custom command) with the same tag. These \eqmathboxes are simple `\eqmakebox`es from the package, with their argument flush left, in math mode and displaystyle. Each box with the same tag has the width of the widest  content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1][l]{$\displaystyle#2$}}


\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\alpha_1 &=\eqmathbox{\frac{1}{4}\left[(L-1)^2 + \tan ^2\left(\frac{2\pi}{M}\right)(L+1)^2\right]}\\
\alpha_2 &= 1 \\
\alpha_3 &=\alpha_1\\
\alpha_4 &=\alpha_1
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
The angle $\theta$ values are
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\theta_1 &= \eqmathbox{\tan^{-1} \left[\frac{L+1}{L-1}\tan\left(\frac{2\pi}{M}\right)\right]}\\
\theta_2 &= \pi - \theta_1\\
\theta_3 &=\theta_1\\
\theta_4 &=\frac{(M-2)\pi}{M} - \theta_1
\end{align}
\end{subequations}\vskip -6ex
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\shortintertext{and}
\phi_1 &=\eqmathbox{ \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta_1}\\
\phi_2 &= \frac{2\pi}{M}\\
\phi_3 &= \phi_1\\
\phi_4 &= \frac{2\pi}{M} + \theta_1
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are two arguments defined for `\eqmathbox` but when you actually use it, you only forward one argument. How is that?

Comment: One is optional, since I give it the value `M` (stands for ‘Math’). It is necessary to have this argument if you want use this code for different groups in your document.  Here, there's only one group, so it uses the default.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use `changepage` package with `adjustwidth`. This environment has two mandatory arguments: `{<left>}` which adds specific amount of left margin, and `{<right>}` which adds specific amount of right margin. The argument `{<left>}` is what you need and you must do some trial and error to determine how much exactly you need for the left margin.

```
\documentclass[]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{changepage}


\begin{document}


\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
    \alpha_1 &=\frac{1}{4}\left[(L-1)^2 + \tan ^2\left(\frac{2\pi}{M}\right)(L+1)^2\right]\\
    \alpha_2 &= 1 \\
    \alpha_3 &=\alpha_1\\
    \alpha_4 &=\alpha_1
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

The angle $\theta$ values are
\begin{adjustwidth}{-15.2mm}{0mm}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
        \theta_1 &= \tan^{-1} \left[\frac{L+1}{L-1}\tan\left(\frac{2\pi}{M}\right)\right]\\
        \theta_2 &= \pi - \theta_1\\
        \theta_3 &=\theta_1\\
        \theta_4 &=\frac{(M-2)\pi}{M} - \theta_1\\[5pt]
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}
\end{adjustwidth}

and
\begin{adjustwidth}{-42mm}{0mm}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
        \phi_1 &= \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta_1\\
        \phi_2 &= \frac{2\pi}{M}\\
        \phi_3 &= \phi_1\\
        \phi_4 &= \frac{2\pi}{M} + \theta_1 
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMNSHO, if you are going to align the 12 `=` symbols in order to give a clear unified look to the 12 equations, you should also use a single `parentequation` counter, i.e., use a single `subequations` (and `align`) environment, in order to provide more visual consistency to the way the equations are presented.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\shortintertext' macro
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\alpha_1 &=\frac{1}{4}\Bigl[(L-1)^2 
           +\tan^2\Bigl(\frac{2\pi}{M}\Bigr)
           (L+1)^2\Bigr]\\
\alpha_2 &= 1 \\
\alpha_3 &=\alpha_1\\
\alpha_4 &=\alpha_1\\
\intertext{The angle $\theta$ values are}
\addtocounter{parentequation}{1}
\theta_1 &= \tan^{-1} \Bigl[\frac{L+1}{L-1}
            \tan\Bigl(\frac{2\pi}{M}\Bigr)\Bigr]\\
\theta_2 &= \pi - \theta_1\\
\theta_3 &=\theta_1\\
\theta_4 &=\frac{(M-2)\pi}{M} - \theta_1
\shortintertext{and}
\phi_1 &= \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta_1\\
\phi_2 &= \frac{2\pi}{M}\\
\phi_3 &= \phi_1\\
\phi_4 &= \frac{2\pi}{M} + \theta_1 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

---

In fact, I'd go even further to provide a "unified" look, by changing the fraction notation in some of the equations to inline fraction style.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\shortintertext' macro
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\alpha_1 &=\tfrac{1}{4}\bigl[(L-1)^2 
           +\tan^2(2\pi/M)
           (L+1)^2\bigr]\\
\alpha_2 &= 1 \\
\alpha_3 &=\alpha_1\\
\alpha_4 &=\alpha_1\\
\intertext{The angle $\theta$ values are}
\addtocounter{parentequation}{1}
\theta_1 &= \tan^{-1} \bigl[(L+1)/(L-1)\tan(2\pi/M)\bigr]\\
\theta_2 &= \pi - \theta_1\\
\theta_3 &=\theta_1\\
\theta_4 &=(M-2)\pi/M - \theta_1
\shortintertext{and}
\phi_1 &= \pi/2 - \theta_1\\
\phi_2 &= 2\pi/M\\
\phi_3 &= \phi_1\\
\phi_4 &= 2\pi/M + \theta_1 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```